# WebDAV client Library for iOS and Mac OS

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, webdav

I would like to be able to access a WebDAV server from my iOS 7+ and Mac OS app. Does anyone know to a good and reliable library to support this?

I have been searching for a library quit a while now but so far I hadn't any success. Of course there are several threads about this topic (here on SO and elsewhere) but most of theme are quite out dated.

`DZWebDAVClient` looks quite promising. But it is based on an older version of `AFNetworking` has not been update for quite a while. I have not been able to find any working example and was not able to get a connection to my own WebDAV server.

The same is true for `wtclient` and `ConnectionKit`

Has someone used a WebDAV client library in production? Any recommendations what lib can be used or which one is not good?

Comment: Why the vote down? Would be great if I would know what I could do better...

Answer (score 0):

Please look at [GCDWebServer](https://github.com/swisspol/GCDWebServer)
it includes webdav library for MAC OSX and IOS

Comment: Thank you for the hint. The project looks really interesting but is about a WebDAV **Server**. I am looking for a solution to let an iOS app act as WebDAV **Client**.

Comment: it is also for ios you can also integrate it in ios

Comment: Sure, but still it is **Server** control and I need a **Client** control. I need a library to access a WebDAV Server and not to create one...